# Android Firebase Database to Java ArrayList or Map

Tags: java, android, json, firebase, arraylist

I have the following Firebase DB: 
-key
--Ingredients
----milk
------ingrName: "milk"
------ingrQty: "2"
------measureName: "dl"
----sugar
------ingrName: "sugar"
------ingrQty: "500"
------measureName: "g"

I want to save it to ArrayList:
**EDITED:**

```
ArrayList<Ingredients> list=new ArrayList<Ingredients>();
databaseReference.child(key).child("Ingredients").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for(DataSnapshot data:dataSnapshot.getChildren()){                       
                    Ingredients ingr=data.getValue(Ingredients.class);                       
                    list.add(ingr);
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            }
        });
        System.out.println("LIST VALUES:");
        System.out.println(list);
        System.out.println("Size: "+list.size());
        System.out.println("OrderedNames: ");
        for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++){
            System.out.println(list.get(i).getIngredientName());
        }
```

**Ingredients class:**

```
public class Ingredients  {

   String ingredientName;
   String ingredientQty;
   String measureName;

    public Ingredients(){
    }

    public Ingredients(String IngredientName,String IngredientQty,String MeasureName){
        this.ingredientName=IngredientName;
        this.ingredientQty=IngredientQty;
        this.measureName=MeasureName;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return super.toString();
    }
}
```

If you have a better solution **(for example saving to Map instead of ArrayList)** please post it.
If I run the code above first time the `list` is empty, but If I press the button second time the Ingredients will be added to my `list`.

**EDIT**
I've tested it, the problem is ValueEventListener always runs at the end, after I want to use the list (and it's still empty).

Comment: Please post your LogCat.

Comment: If I want to print `System.out.println("LIST VALUES:");
            System.out.println(list);` I got this:  I/System.out: LIST VALUES:
I/System.out: [] ...the list is empty

Answer (score 0):

In your "Ingredients class" change the variable name with your firebase attribute name. like
String ingredientQty; to, String ingrQty;

also, use getter and setter in the class.

For saving into arrylist your code is right but u have to case while getting the data.

Comment: it's the same, I have misspelled it, sorry. From one of my activity i have saved this data, now I want to get it.

Comment: If I want to print this:  `for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++){
                System.out.println(list.get(i).getIngredientName());                
            }` I got the following logcat: `No setter/field for milk found on class com.xx.xx.xx.Ingredients`